# ¿Se puede crear una categoría por defecto para tipos de publicaciones?

Tags: php, wordpress, categorical

En mis intentos de adentrarme un poco más en WordPress se me vino a la mente la siguiente duda:

¿Es posible asociar una `categoría` por defecto a `customs posts types`?

En un caso hipotético tengo una página de animales y cuento con distintos `posts types` para diferentes tipos de publicación según su grupo, por ejemplo: `Aves, Reptiles, Mamíferos`.

Como valor por defecto ¿puedo asociar una `categoría` llamada `"aves"` al `custom posts` de Aves, una `categoria` `"reptiles"` para las publicaciones de `Reptiles`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te entiendo bien, tienes distintos Custom Post Types de `aves`, `reptiles`, y `mamiferos`, y también un taxonomy de `category` asociado a estos Custom Post Types.

Pues sí, y me parece que la mejor manera de hacerlo es con un *hook* de `save_post` o `save_post_{$post->post_type}`. Así que cuando guardas un post del post_type determinado, la categoría se asigna automáticamente, como lo siguiente

```
// Hay que reemplazar {$post->post_type} con tu custom_post_type, por ejemplo 'aves'. 
// Así la función aplica solo a post_type 'aves'.    

add_action( 'save_post_aves', 'mi_categoria_por_defecto', 20, 2 );

function mi_categoria_por_defecto( $id, $post ) {

    // 1. Definir lo que quieres cambiar
    $terms = 'aves'; // slug de la categoría
    $taxonomy = 'category'; // el nombre del taxonomy, o cualquier otro, si usas 'custom taxonomy'
    
    // 2. Cambiar el taxonomy del post
    wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $terms, $taxonomy, true );  
}
```

O si quieres automatizarlo un poco, puedes hacer lo siguiente con solo `save_post` (genérico)

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mi_categoria_por_defecto', 20, 2 );

function mi_categoria_por_defecto( $id, $post ) {

    // 1. Limitar esta acción a ciertos post types
    if ( !in_array( $post->post_type, ['aves', 'reptiles', 'mamiferos'] ):
        return; // salir ahora si el post guardado no pertenece a estos post types
    endif;

    // 2. Definir lo que quieres cambiar, usando el post_type pasado por la acción
    $terms = $post->post_type; // slug de la categoría
    $taxonomy = 'category'; // el nombre del taxonomy, o cualquier otro, si usas 'custom taxonomy'
    
    // 3. Cambiar el taxonomy del post
    wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $terms, $taxonomy, true );  
}
```